# Make multiple data 'visible' or 'hidden' using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, logic

I need your support in selecting a logic. My script pulls few rows from DB and displays on screen. I want to give a feedback form for each data. These feedback forms must be hidden and should be visible on click of a text (Like reply to this) - Pls refer the picture.

[image: Sample record]

I have tried with the help of java script and CSS

```
<script>
function hideElement()
{
document.getElementById("target").style.display="none";
}
function showElement()
{
document.getElementById("target").style.display="block";
}
</script>


// Data-1 fetched from DB goes here
<a href='#target'>Reply to this post</a>
<span id='target' style='display:none'>
// Feedback form for Data 1 here
</span>

// Data-2 fetched from DB goes here
<a href='#target'>Reply to this post</a>
<span id='target' style='display:none'>
// Feedback form for Data 2 here
</span>
```

But it works only for the first record, - Javascript finds the first object with the name "target" and sets display property 'none' or 'block'

What logic can I use to generate dynamic ID assigned to each record and make java sript to run for that. Are there any other better logics to do this? (I'm sure ther are)

Comment: `id`'s must be unique. `document.getElementById("target")` will only select a single element, in this case the first one it finds with that `id`. You will want to use `class` and [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Name them `target1` and `target2` or something.

Comment: In your HTML you have two items with the same `id`, by unique I mean only one element can have that `id`. You will need to either use a different `id` or you can make them into a `class`.

Comment: I can make unique IDs for each data, but how should I point those IDs from Java Script? Should I generate script for each IDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Element IDs must be unique, but any time you find yourself generating unique IDs for repeating elements there's probably a simpler, more generic way to implement whatever you're doing.

For this type of function you don't need IDs at all, you can use classes and DOM navigation to get from the clicked item to the related span, using a single delegated event handler as follows:

```js
// bind click handler to the document
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // test if the actual clicked item has the class "reply"
  if (e.target.className.match(/\breply\b/)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // find the related target span
    var target = e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".target");
    // update its visibility
    target.style.display = target.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<div>  <!-- note added wrapper div -->
  <a href='#target' class="reply">Reply to this post</a>
  <span class='target' style='display:none'>
      Feedback form for Data 1 here
  </span>
</div>
<div>  <!-- note added wrapper div -->
  <a href='#target' class="reply">Reply to this post</a>
  <span class='target' style='display:none'>
      Feedback form for Data 2 here
  </span>
</div>
```

I've put some comments within the above JS to explain what it's doing, but the important line is this one:

```
var target = e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".target");
```

Within the event listener, the `e` argument is the `event` object which holds various bits of information about the event being handled. `e.target` tells which element was clicked. Having already tested that element's class to see if it was one of the "reply" anchors, we then use the `.parentNode` property to get a reference to the wrapper div that I added to your markup, then from there `.querySelector(".target")` finds a descendant of the div that has the class `target`.

As you can see I've modified your html to support the above as follows:

1. Change the span ids to be classes
2. Given the anchors `class="reply"`
3. Added wrapper div elements for each group, to make the DOM navigation simple and reliable. You could navigate from the anchor to the span using `e.target.nextSibling`, except then you'd have to add extra code to skip over any text nodes. I find a wrapper element easier to work with. Of course, if your elements are *already* in some kind of wrappers for other purposes then you can just use the existing wrappers.

Note: it would be good to remove the inline styles, and to show and hide the spans by adding and removing classes rather than directly updating their styles, but that's not really the main issue here so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/BzmAwg

Step 1: ditch those IDs

### markup

```
<ul class="item-list">
    <li>
        <p>default stuff</p>
        <div class="hidden-thing">
            hidden stuff
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>default stuff</p>
        <div class="hidden-thing">
            hidden stuff
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>default stuff</p>
        <div class="hidden-thing">
            hidden stuff
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Step 2: hide the hidden stuff in CSS and not inline

### styles

(this is stylus syntax.. but same point)

```
.item-list
    list-style: none
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    li
        background: gray
        padding: .5rem
        margin-bottom: 1rem
        cursor: pointer
        .hidden-thing
            display: none // hide it
```

Step 3: get the thing you want to click with jquery or with vanilla JavaScript - attach event handler - use `this` to note what element the event happens on - with that element... traverse down the DOM and find the thing you want - then use the show method, whichs sets display: block... or fadeIn() or animate() or whatever you like.

### JavaScript

```
$('.item-list li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.hidden-thing').show();
});

// or... 
$('.item-list li').on('click', function() {
    $('.item-list li').find('.hidden-thing').hide();
    $(this).find('.hidden-thing').show();
});
```

If you want only one hidden thing open at a time, you can hide all the items each time first - which is kinda janky, but usual.

BUT... there is a better way to do this, where you add an active class to the whole item. This lets you style things inside it and just generally gives you a larger scope to work with. Here is an example of that. : ) It uses .closest - and passes the event into the click handler to stop the outer click action from bubbling up:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/oLoqEy